# Animated Smooth Indicator not Working ? FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm building an app with a `PageView` Widget and I wanted to add `AnimatedSmoothIndicator`.

I added a `CarouseLslider` to the `pageView` to make it auto run

but it never changes .. I tried a lot of methods but none of them work

can anyone help..

```
class FoodPageBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const FoodPageBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FoodPageBody> createState() => _FoodPageBodyState();
}

class _FoodPageBodyState extends State<FoodPageBody> {
  
  PageController pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 1);

  int activeIndex = 0;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 340,
      child: PageView.builder(
          controller: pageController,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return _bulidPageItem(position);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _bulidPageItem(int index) {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slide image 
    return Column(
      children: [
        CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
              setState(() {
                activeIndex = index;
              });
            },
            enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
            enableInfiniteScroll: true,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            autoPlayCurve: Curves.ease,
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 5),
            height: 320,
          ),
          items: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
                  height: 220,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: index.isEven
                        ? const Color(0xFFffd28d)
                        : const Color(0xFF89dad0),
                    image: const DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('images/chineseFood.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ),
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slide Information 
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    margin:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 15),
                    height: 130,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                            blurRadius: 6,
                            spreadRadius: 0.7,
                            offset: const Offset(1, 4))
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
//------------------------------------------------
// Slider title
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const BigText(
                            text: 'Chinese side',
                          ),
//----------------------------------------------
// Slider Rating
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Wrap(
                                children: List.generate(
                                  5,
                                  (index) => const Icon(Icons.star,
                                      color: AppColor.mainColor, size: 12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 10),
                              SmallText(text: 4.5.toString()),
                              const SizedBox(width: 10),
                              const SmallText(text: '1287 comments'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
//----------------------------------------------
// Slider Icons
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: const [
                              SliderIcons(
                                  color: AppColor.iconColor1,
                                  text: 'Normal',
                                  icon: Icons.circle),
                              SliderIcons(
                                  color: AppColor.mainColor,
                                  text: '1.7km',
                                  icon: Icons.location_pin),
                              SliderIcons(
                                  color: AppColor.iconColor2,
                                  text: '32min',
                                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.clock),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slider Dots 
        AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
          activeIndex: activeIndex,
          count: 5,
          effect: const WormEffect(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any specific reason having both Pageview and `CarouselSlider`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here, the `CarouselSlider`'s `items` is just one of this snippet. Therefore, `onPageChanged` active index is always getting 0.
To have five items, we need to generate item here.

I think pageView is not necessary for this case.

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(height: 340, child: _bulidPageItem());
  }

  Widget _bulidPageItem() {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slide image 
    return Column(
      children: [
        CarouselSlider(
          carouselController: carouselController,
          options: CarouselOptions(
            onPageChanged: (index1, reason) {
              debugPrint("on Page changed $index1");
              setState(() {
                activeIndex = index1;
              });
            },
          ),
          items: List.generate(
            5,
            (index) => Stack(
```